# Firebase - Variables out of scope

Tags: javascript, scope, console, firebase

Forgive me if this is an amateur question, I'm new to using APIs. I've been working with Firebase to store a "scores" list array which is used throughout my script. Within one of the Firebase functions, the value is updated, but the value isn't updated within the global scope. I'm not sure what I'm missing at this point. Here's a code snippet, the values of 0 and 1 are logged on console.

```
window.global_counter = 0;
window.score = 0;
window.listScores = {"GMS":0, "Vacc":0, "CH":0, "GSF":0, "Pharm":0, "GF":0, "Pharma":0, "Sti":0};

var ref = new Firebase("https://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.firebaseio.com/");

// show chart data 
ref.on("value", function(snapshot){
    listScores["GMS"] = snapshot.child("GMS").numChildren();
    console.log("listScores['GMS'] inside: " + listScores["GMS"]);
    // 1
    listScores["Vacc"] = snapshot.child("Vacc").numChildren();
    listScores["CH"] = snapshot.child("CH").numChildren();
    listScores["GSF"] = snapshot.child("GSF").numChildren();
    listScores["Pharm"] = snapshot.child("Pharm").numChildren();
    listScores["GF"] = snapshot.child("GF").numChildren();
    listScores["Pharma"] = snapshot.child("Pharma").numChildren();
    listScores["Sti"] = snapshot.child("Sti").numChildren();
});

console.log("listScores['GMS'] outside: " + listScores["GMS"]);
// 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a scope issue per-say. Firebase returns data asynchronously.

Firebase downloads the data over the network. It does this asynchronously, so it doesn't block UI activity. The will eventually download, but not by the time you log it in your script.

You have a few options to work with async data.

1. Do all of your logic in the `.on()` function.
2. Use an observable or another framework like [Angular+AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/) that simplifies async data.

Comment: I tried the first option, but received the same results. The second seems like of a pain, but I'll keep it as a last resort. Thanks for the response, David.

Comment: The first option should work. Can you update your code?

Comment: The first and second time I tried the transfer into the on function, it didn't work. I did some editing and it worked the third time around. Thanks for the help!