# How to get data from db

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data from the db, but it does not work
How to get data from bd?

```
const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = fire.database();
const thisDb = db.ref().child('rooms');
thisDb.on('value', (snap) => {
  console.log(snap);
});
```

console

[image]

data from db

[image]

Comment: Use this reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: why the variables that I assign inside thisDb.on ('value', (snap) => {}); not visible from the outside?

`let arr = [];

thisDb.on('value', (snap) => {
  arr = snap.val();
});

console.log(arr); // empty`

Comment: The callback you pass into `on` is called asynchronously, once the data is loaded from Firebase. Since this may take some time, when you try to access the data *outside* of this callback, it likely hasn't loaded yet. The solution is to only use the data *inside* the callback, or to use a promise. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643970, https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474546, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068397, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33807995